# Selecting patterns

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have data as a list of four element lists, some with missing data, thus

```
{{214.1699982, 113.5199966, "miss", 117.}, {214.0899963, 124.4199982, 
  "miss", 129.}, {195.4199982, 110.3600006, 79., 123.}, {"miss", 
  125.6399994, 77., 127.}, {197.9900055, "miss", 84., 
  119.}, {213.3800049, 122.4100037, 80., 123.}, {"miss", 126.2699966, 
  83., 123.}, {"miss", 113.5400009, 78., 128.}, {"miss", 130.9700012, 
  81., 126.}, {208.8800049, "miss", 79., 113.}}
```

I need to count which have full data and which are missing for each element position, like this
[image]

Have tried Select, Pick, Cases with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the data:

```
d = {{214.1699982, 113.5199966, "miss", 117.}, {214.0899963, 
    124.4199982, "miss", 129.}, {195.4199982, 110.3600006, 79., 
    123.}, {"miss", 125.6399994, 77., 127.}, {197.9900055, "miss", 
    84., 119.}, {213.3800049, 122.4100037, 80., 123.}, {"miss", 
    126.2699966, 83., 123.}, {"miss", 113.5400009, 78., 
    128.}, {"miss", 130.9700012, 81., 126.}, {208.8800049, "miss", 
    79., 113.}};
```

we define the following patterns, allowing for at most 2 misses:

```
pattern = {
  {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, 
  {_?NumericQ, _ NumericQ, _?NumericQ, "miss"},
  {_?NumericQ,"miss", _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, 
  {"miss", _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ},
  {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, "miss", "miss"},
  {_?NumericQ, "miss", _?NumericQ, "miss"},
  {"miss", _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ, "miss"},
  {_?NumericQ, "miss", "miss", _?NumericQ},
  {"miss", _?NumericQ, "miss", _?NumericQ},
  {"miss", "miss", _?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}
  }
```

Then we count how many times each pattern appears:

```
co = Count[d, #] & /@ pattern;
```

Then for the displayt we change the patterns to 0 and 1's:

```
patdis = StringReplace[
    ToString[pattern], {"_?NumericQ" -> "1", "miss" -> "0"}] // 
   ToExpression;
```

And here is the result:

```
Grid[Prepend[Transpose[{co, patdis}], {"Frequency", "Pattern"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
tuples = Tuples[{0, 1}, Length @ First @ d];

boole = Boole @ Map[NumericQ, d, {-1}];

Prepend[{"pattern", "count"}] @ Transpose[{tuples, Count[boole, #] & /@ tuples}] // 
 Grid[#, Dividers -> {Center, {False, True, {False}}}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 data={{214.1699982, 113.5199966, "miss", 117.}, {214.0899963, 124.4199982, 
  "miss", 129.}, {195.4199982, 110.3600006, 79., 123.}, {"miss", 
  125.6399994, 77., 127.}, {197.9900055, "miss", 84., 
  119.}, {213.3800049, 122.4100037, 80., 123.}, {"miss", 126.2699966, 
  83., 123.}, {"miss", 113.5400009, 78., 128.}, {"miss", 130.9700012, 
  81., 126.}, {208.8800049, "miss", 79., 113.}}



 Tally[Replace[data, {_Real -> 1, _String -> 0}, Infinity]] // Grid
```

Output

{1,1,0,1}   2

{1,1,1,1}   2

{0,1,1,1}   4

{1,0,1,1}   2

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `Association` and `Dataset`:

```
dt = 
    {{214., 113., "miss", 117.}, {214., 124., "miss", 129.},
     {195., 110.,79., 123.}, {"miss", 125., 77., 127.}, 
     {197., "miss", 84., 119.}, {213., 122., 80., 123.}, 
     {"miss", 126., 83., 123.}, {"miss", 113., 78., 128.}, 
     {"miss", 130., 81., 126.}, {208., "miss", 79., 113.}};

ds = <|Thread[Tuples[{0, 1}, 4] -> 0], Counts[dt /. {_Real -> 1, _String -> 0}]|>;

<|"Pattern" -> "Count", #, "Total" -> Total @ #|> & @ ds //
  Dataset[#, Alignment -> Right, HeaderBackground -> White] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
d = {{214.1699982, 113.5199966, "miss", 117.}, {214.0899963, 
    124.4199982, "miss", 129.}, {195.4199982, 110.3600006, 79., 
    123.}, {"miss", 125.6399994, 77., 127.}, {197.9900055, "miss", 
    84., 119.}, {213.3800049, 122.4100037, 80., 123.}, {"miss", 
    126.2699966, 83., 123.}, {"miss", 113.5400009, 78., 
    128.}, {"miss", 130.9700012, 81., 126.}, {208.8800049, "miss", 
    79., 113.}};

(lut = d /. "miss" -> 0 // Unitize // GroupBy[#, Identity, Length] &);
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];

res = {#, First@Lookup[lut, {#}, 0]} & /@ t

    
Prepend[res, {"pattern", "count"}] // 
  Append[{"Total", res // Map[Last] // Total}] // 
 Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using data:

```
d = {{214.1699982, 113.5199966, "miss", 117.}, {214.0899963, 
    124.4199982, "miss", 129.}, {195.4199982, 110.3600006, 79., 
    123.}, {"miss", 125.6399994, 77., 127.}, {197.9900055, "miss", 
    84., 119.}, {213.3800049, 122.4100037, 80., 123.}, {"miss", 
    126.2699966, 83., 123.}, {"miss", 113.5400009, 78., 
    128.}, {"miss", 130.9700012, 81., 126.}, {208.8800049, "miss", 
    79., 113.}};
```

Using [`Unitize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unitize.html), [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html)

```
Module[{a, f}, 
 a = {Row[#, "  "], 
     Lookup[KeyMap[f, 
       GroupBy[Unitize[d /. "miss" -> 0], # &, Length]], f[#], 0]} & /@
    IntegerDigits[Range[0, 15], 2, 4];
 Prepend[a, {"Pattern", "Count"}] // Grid]
```

yields:
[image]

If data can contain 0 the above would need modification, e.g.:

```
Module[{a, f}, 
 a = {Row[#, "  "], 
     Lookup[KeyMap[f, 
       GroupBy[MapAt[Boole@*NumericQ, d, {All, All}], # &, Length]], 
      f[#], 0]} & /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 15], 2, 4];
 Prepend[a, {"Pattern", "Count"}] // Grid]
```